# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient

Tags: angular

This is the error i am getting while testing after upgrading to `angular 12`.

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!

i tried adding **HttpClientModule** to imports array of **TestBed.configureTestingModule**

even my project has server-side rendering .

Please help me with this,  i have tried all solutions available but still getting same error

Comment: Are you getting this error while running your tests, if any?

Comment: yes project is running but whenever i trying for ng test , for unit testing , i am getting this error

Comment: Then you should add `HttpClientModule` to your imports array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` as said in the answer. Let's give it a try :)

Comment: i tried this but still getting this error -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                  

 .beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [ BasicFeaturesComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

Comment: Have a check with importing `HttpClientTestingModule` instead or both :)

Comment: yes i tried this --------------- imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule, 
 HttpClientModule  ],------------- but still getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have HttpClientModule in app.module.ts :

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and this :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
   ]
 })
```

Comment: thanks fr response , but i have already tried this solution but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import `HttpClientModule` after `BrowserModule` in `app.module.ts` file as shown below, if not imported already like that order.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, assuming that you might get this error while running your tests. Then you should add `HttpClientModule` to your imports array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` too like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [HttpClientModule],
   ...
});
```

or even better (if you want to mock request):

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
   ...
});
```

Comment: tried this solution , but still getting same error . please help on this error. our project is using server-side rendering .

Comment: Are you doing any mock request to get the data?

Comment: tried this ------ imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], --- but still gettting same errror

Comment: yes in some place we are doing mock request